# ¿Cómo extraer el valor de un elemento xml que tiene namespaces con xPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespace

Intento obtener el valor de un elemento de un xml; algunos de los elementos/nodos tienen un espacio de nombres.
He revisado varios hilos en Stackoverflow y no consigo que funcione, siempre devuelve vacio `""`

Inicializar objetos:

```
//libs
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(xmlFINAL);//ruta absoluta al xml
XPath xPath = (XPath) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

NamespaceContext que usará xPath:

```
NamespaceContext nsContext = new NamespaceContext (){
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                 if (prefix == null) {            
                        throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
                  } else if ("ns2".equals(prefix)) {            
                        return "http://ns2";
                  }else{
                      return "http://ns1";
                  }

            }

            public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }

            public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }

        };
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsContext);
```

Obtener valor:

```
String expression = "/elemento_root/elemento1/ns2:elemento2/ns2:elemento3/text()";
String valor = (String) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.STRING);
```

XML ejemplo (el que utilizo es muy grande):

```
<elemento_root xmlns="http://ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2">
    <elemento1>
    ...
        <ns2:elemento2>
            <ns2:elemento3>quiero este valor</elemento3>
        </elemento2>
    ...
    </elemento1>
</elemento_root>
```

**Edit 1:**
He hecho pruebas sin tener namespaces en el xml + desactivando setNamespaceContext y funciona.

**Edit 2:**

Aunque no funcionen las urls de los namespaces, haciendolo de esta manera sí funciona:

```
Node node = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS("ns2", "elemento3");
String valor= node.getTextContent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría se ve bien tu xpath, pero tal vez no hay acceso al xsd. Revisa que las urls a donde va el espacio de nombres, también se resuelvan. Si no resuelven, ese es el problema, tal vez te falten credenciales, permisos o tal vez haya cambiado la ruta.

Comment: No había pensado en eso, de hecho las urls de los namespace no funcionan. No puedo probarlo porque no tengo los xds (ni las urls) correctos, pero seguro que es ese el problema. En caso contrario volveré a comentar aqui.

Comment: He añadido **Edit 2**, aunque claro , no es xpath, es de la librería  org.w3c.dom

Comment: Es correcto que funcione con xml + desactivando setNamespaceContext o agregando ns2 pero el asunto aqui es que aunque ahora tienes el namespace y puedes acceder para leer resulta que ese namespace no esta siendo validado por un XSD